# How to get in a vb.net combobox the result of a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

The stored procedure:

```
select sum(column) 
from table
```

returns only one column, one row from a given table.

In the vb.net form I don't want to use a datagridview to get the sum in a one cell table, I want to get the sum in a simple combobox. It's possible?

```
   ...  
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("stored_procedure", con)    
   con.Open()  
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure  
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text  
   Dim dtc As New DataTable  
   dtc.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())  
   con.Close()  
   DataGridView1.DataSource = dtc ' this is working  
   ComboBox1.DataSource = dtc  ' for this I get System.Data.DataRowView in combo 
   ...
```

Thank you

Comment: If your SQL code is returning only a single row, single column (like here in the case of `SELECT COUNT(*)...` , you can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` (instead of `ExecuteReader`) to get that single value returned much more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
ComboBox1.text = dtc.Rows(0).Item(0).tostring
```

or a combination of combobox1.clear and combobox1.add